# Changing search function of Jquerygrid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using [this](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx) plugin in my asp.net mvc application.

Jquerygrid search function working as expecting. But I want only search with "contains or not". How can I do that?

My search picture is shown below:
[image]

Comment: Exactly which grid plugin are you using? Please add a link to the plugin homepage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `SearchOptions` list on the `JQGridColumn` to specify which filter criteria you want to use for a given column.

If you leave the `SearchOptions` empty then it will display all the search rules, so you need to write something like this:

```cs
private void SetUpSearchDialogGrid(JQGrid grid)
{   
    var column = grid.Columns.Find(c => c.DataField == "Id");
    //...

    column.SearchOptions.Add(SearchOperation.Contains);
    column.SearchOptions.Add(SearchOperation.DoesNotContain);                

    //..
}
```